# Prediction Error Curves - Brier score

Tags: r

I have a set of patients which are divided in a training and validation set. I would like to evaluate the performance of several parameters for stratifying overall survival. I therefore use the pec package (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pec/pec.pdf) to generate prediction error curves and the integrated brier score (IBS). The question that I have is whether there is a way to determine if the IBS of Model_1 is significantly lower as compared to Model_2 or the reference model?

Thanks for your help!

```
models <- list("Model_1" = coxph(Surv(OS, OS_event)~ var_1+var_2, data=df_train),
               "Model_2" = coxph(Surv(OS, OS_event) ~ var_3+var_4, data=df_train))


brier <- pec(object=models,
             data=df_validate,
             formula=Surv(OS, OS_event)~age,
             exact=TRUE,
             cens.model="marginal",
             traindata = df_train)
plot(brier)
print(brier)
```

Comment: They are not nested models so the usual methods that depend on marginality will not be informative. Some people believe that using some information criterion lets you get around that limitation. I'm not so sure about that. Perhaps you should post some actual results? At the moment this seems too vague to offer a coded answer which is what StackOverflow is supposed to be delivering.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to run the cross validation many times and then use a t-test or wilcox test (non-parametric version) to determine if there is a statistically significant difference between the IBS of model 1 and model 2. A low P-value rejects the null hypothesis that the mean IBS score of model 1 and model 2 are equal.

Suppose the IBS scores are stored in a dataframe called TEALL where column 1 are the scores for model 1 and column 2 are the scores for model 2. Each row represents another cross validation. Then:

```
ttest = t.test(TEALL[,1], TEALL[,2], paired=TRUE)
wtest = wilcox.test(TEALL[,1], TEALL[,2],paired=TRUE)
```